# Multiple static VPN gateways on for Azure VPN Gateway workaround?

Tags: vpn, azure, windows-server-2016, site-to-site-vpn

I have an Azure infrastructure environment with multiple VM's and an Azure VPN Gateway for both Point 2 site (RDP, SSMS) connections, and multiple site 2 site connections for connecting to external networks (customers)

The requirement of needing multiple site2site connecties forced me to use the dynamic routing vpn-type. However I now have a customer that cannot and will not change their legacy VPN, that only supports static routing.

I cannot add another (static) VPN gateway to the same virtual network, but are there workarounds for this? Can I create a 2nd Vnet, attach a static VPN gateway to this. And then connect Vnet-to-Vnet using the VPN gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, it is impossible.

For static VPN gateway, you only could create a S2S VPN connection. According to your scenario, you have created a S2S VPN connection, you could not create a VNet-to-VNet using the VPN gateway.

Even you use Vnet Peering, it is also impossible. **VNet peering is between two virtual networks, and there is no derived transitive relationship.**

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep looking for a solution then. Any idea by the way of support for both static and dynamic routing on the same gateway will be available anytime in the future?